# How do I disable pop-up notifications in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, notification

How can i disable ALL pop-up notification on Xubuntu 11.10

I have tried:  `sudo apt-get remove notify-osd`

Which resulted in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package notify-osd is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Obviously removing `notify-osd` won't work because Xubuntu doesn't use it, it uses `xfce4-notifyd`.

So if you want to *remove* them, remove that package.

```
 sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd
```

If you only want to disable them use this:

```
 sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service.disabled
```

To reverse that:

```
 sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service.disabled /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service
```

[Source.](http://bitonic.org/blog/?p=24)

Comment: Awesome! thanks! but now sound +/- buttons on keyboard do not work! ((

Comment: Well no, `xfce4-notifyd` works with `xfce4-volumed`..

Comment: I have install $ xfce4-notifyd

Comment: back and $ xfce4-volumed     to but buttons still dose not work

Comment: If you remove the Notifications daemon the Volume daemon doesn't work.

Comment: ok and when I install notifucations daemon back & still the Volume daemon doesn't work ?

Comment: When you re install the Notifications, the daemon will work again thus the Volume daemon will work again as intended.

Comment: I have reinstall Notifications, make reboot, & Voluem buttons dosen't work

Answer (score 5):

you can also run this command and will be able to edit what you want to be shown or blocked in notifications. I had to do this for SMB4K for drive mounts as it was driving me nuts lol.

xfce4-notifyd-config

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service.disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system notifyd is managed by systemd, and is in the user space.

`$ systemctl --user disable xfce4-notifyd`

This was sufficient for me when I switched to dunst